# JPA: lazy load slick moment

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, lazy-loading

As I understand, lazyLoadedObject in JPA might be not loaded even after using of it getter method. So in example below, after stroke 1, lazilyLoadededPerson might be still null, and only after stroke 2 the container will run the query to the db.

```
lazilyLoadedPerson = runQueryToLoadPerson();
lazilyLoadedPerson.getName();
```

***My question is***: Does the code below contain an error in stroke 2?

```
lazilyLoadedPerson = runQueryToLoadPerson(); 
if (lazilyLoadedPerson != null) { //if lazilyLoadedPerson == null suppose that such person doesn't exists in database
  return lazilyLoadedPerson.getName(); 
}
```

*Why I consider that it will be an error:*
after the stroke 1 in the example above, the lazilyLoadedPerson will be null even the lazilyLoadedPerson exists in the database. We have the situation when the entity exists in the database but the getName() method will be never invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

A lazily loaded object is *never* null.

### Longer answer

The explanation is valid for *Hibernate* but other JPA-providers should be similar. See [the official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching) for a detailed explanation of how lazy loading works or [this short article](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one) for a short one. But the core facts are:

If for some reason or another *Hibernate* decides to lazily load an object, you don't get the object you wanted but a proxy to that object instead (i.e. **not** a `null`-reference). As soon as you call something on that proxy that can only be known by accessing the database, the proxy does exactly that. Provided you have an active session (and some other conditions are met) *Hibernate* executes the necessary query and the call returns.

#### Your Example

Let's take your example and extend it with a declaration

```
MyPerson lazilyLoadedPerson = runQueryToLoadPerson(); 
if (lazilyLoadedPerson != null) { //if lazilyLoadedPerson == null suppose that such person doesn't exists in database
    return lazilyLoadedPerson.getName(); 
}
```

Assuming you did not define a proxy class for the class `MyPerson`, *Hibernate* has no other option but to actually load the object you wanted from the database. One of the reasons is exactly what you're doing: if it would return `null`, you could not check, whether the object even exists in the database.

### Advice

Worrying about lazy loading can be quite confusing at the beginning. My advice is, not to do that too early. If you're just getting to know JPA, simply annotate all Collections with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` and don't define any proxies and you'll never come across lazy loading.

If you got to know the whole concept a little better, you can read up on lazy loading and change your *xml*-file or annotation accordingly.